# Convert a loop into functional programming using Purrr - but only applying to a vector of variables

Tags: r, functional-programming, dplyr, purrr

I want to iterate over a dataframe - replacing the NA's by the median - but only iterating over a vector of variables

This code works, but I would like to make it more functional (while also incorporating it into other 'Tidy' code). How can I convert section 2 into a functional style and chain it with the expression in section 1?

```
ColsMed <- c("V7", "V9", "V10")

for(i in ColsMed){
wvsFSU[is.na(wvsFSU[,i]), i] <- median(wvsFSU[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

I was trying the below and a number of variants.

```
library(Purrr)
wvsFSU <- map(is.na(wvsFSU), ColsMed, median)
```

It is the looping through a portion of variables rather than the whole dataframe which is tripping me up

Comment: Try `wvsFSU[, ColsMed] <- map(wvsFSU[, ColsMed], ~ replace(., is.na(.), median(.))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is wide. Long format with gather makes the code more dynamic. Here is a solution:

```
wvsFSU %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  gather(k, v, V7, V9, V10) %>% # Enter columns here
  group_by(k) %>% 
  mutate(v = if_else(is.na(v), median(v, na.rm = T), v)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(k,v) %>% 
  select(-rowname)
```